# Describe a result set returned from a stored procedure in the Golang driver for Db2 for LUW

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, db2-luw

I have two tables:

```
create table test2 (
  id integer not null primary key, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100)
)

create table test3 (
  id integer not null primary key, home_address varchar(100), work_address varchar(100)
)
```

I created a stored procedure which selects some columns from each table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "BLUADMIN"."REST_PROCTEST1_1_0"()
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
BEGIN
DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 
 SELECT T2.FIRST_NAME, T2.LAST_NAME, T3.HOME_ADDRESS, T3.WORK_ADDRESS 
 FROM TEST2 T2 INNER JOIN TEST3 T3 ON T2.ID=T3.ID;
OPEN C1;
END
```

I wanted to get a description of the result set. I can describe results of an SQL query using the Db2 command-line processor like so:

```
db2 => describe SELECT T2.FIRST_NAME, T2.LAST_NAME, T3.HOME_ADDRESS, T3.WORK_ADDRESS FROM BLUADMIN.TEST2 T2 INNER JOIN BLUADMIN.TEST3 T3 ON T2.ID=T3.ID

Column Information

Number of columns: 4

SQL type |  Type length | Column name | Name length    
449 VARCHAR | 100 | FIRST_NAME | 10
449 VARCHAR | 100 | LAST_NAME | 9
449 VARCHAR | 100 | HOME_ADDRESS | 12
449 VARCHAR | 100 | WORK_ADDRESS | 12
```

I am using the [Golang driver for Db2](http://github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db), and I am looking for a way to obtain similar information in my program.

Comment: You say you use ODBC and yet you run the `DESCRIBE` command in the CLP. So, which is it? Note though that the metadata of a result set returned from a stored procedure is only available at run time after the result set is associated with the locator in the caller.

Comment: I ran the describe in the CLP to show what I am looking for as a return in ODBC

Comment: In the ODBC application you use `SQLDescribeCol()` for each column after calling the procedure. [Here's an overview](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/odbc/src/tpc/db2z_rcvrslt.html) -- the manual is for Db2 on z/OS, but the ODBC API is the same, obviously.

Comment: I am unable to use the SQLDescribeCol(). I am using the go lang driver for Db2 from https://github.com/ibmdb/go_ibm_db.

Is there another way to get the description of the stored procedure used the go lang driver?

Comment: Then you're not using ODBC. Your question is entirely misleading. Besides, it's off-topic here since it turns out to be programming-related.

Comment: @S.Edouard As regards the CLP, DESCRIBE works for a SELECT statement, but if you use DESCRIBE on a CALL statement the result will *only* show the details of any OUTPUT or INOUT *parameters* in the signature of the stored procedure. It specifically will not describe any result-sets that the stored procedure might return. For golang with ibm_db you are restricted to its API, unless you devise your own extension to access the CLI layer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the answer you want, but you can create the SQL as a temporary view, then query the catalog

E.g

```
CREATE VIEW TEMP AS SELECT T2.FIRST_NAME, T2.LAST_NAME, T3.HOME_ADDRESS, T3.WORK_ADDRESS FROM BLUADMIN.TEST2 T2 INNER JOIN BLUADMIN.TEST3 T3 ON T2.ID=T3.ID;

SELECT COLNO, COLNAME, TYPENAME, LENGTH, SCALE, NULLS   --etc
FROM  SYSCAT.COLUMNS WHERE TABSCHEMA = CURRENT SCHEMA AND TABNAME = 'TEMP';

DROP VIEW TEMP;
```